# Convert a SQL query result table to an HTML table for email

Tags: html, sql, sp-send-dbmail

I am running a SQL query that returns a table of results. I want to send the table in an email using dbo.sp_send_dbMail.

Is there a straightforward way within SQL to turn a table into an HTML table? Currently, I'm manually constructing it using COALESCE and putting the results into a varchar that I use as the emailBody.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You might want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204). An `XQuer FLWOR` based approach taking the SELECT as parameter with support for header, CSS and hyper-links.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is one way to do it from an article titled "[Format query output into an HTML table - the easy way [archive]](https://web.archive.org/web/20120208030043/http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/10/24/format-query-output-into-an-html-table-the-easy-way.aspx)".  You would need to substitute the details of your own query for the ones in this example, which gets a list of tables and a row count.

```
declare @body varchar(max)

set @body = cast( (
select td = dbtable + '</td><td>' + cast( entities as varchar(30) ) + '</td><td>' + cast( rows as varchar(30) )
from (
      select dbtable  = object_name( object_id ),
             entities = count( distinct name ),
             rows     = count( * )
      from sys.columns
      group by object_name( object_id )
      ) as d
for xml path( 'tr' ), type ) as varchar(max) )

set @body = '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">'
          + '<tr><th>Database Table</th><th>Entity Count</th><th>Total Rows</th></tr>'
          + replace( replace( @body, '&lt;', '<' ), '&gt;', '>' )
          + '</table>'

print @body
```

Once you have `@body`, you can then use whatever email mechanism you want.

Comment: It is always very dangerous to create `XML` on string base... Your are replacing `<` and `>`, but there are many more dangerous characters like the `&`. You can check [this answer] for another approach.

Comment: I like the approach. Are you able to add the functionality to add a class to certain rows (i.e every other row to have another CSS class)? I know that I can abstract your solution to use dynamic SQL, though that sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Eli, not in any way that wouldn't be considered more 'hacky' than this already is.

Answer (score 106):

I made a dynamic proc which turns any random query into an HTML table, so you don't have to hardcode columns like in the other responses.

```
-- Description: Turns a query into a formatted HTML table. Useful for emails. 
-- Any ORDER BY clause needs to be passed in the separate ORDER BY parameter.
-- =============================================
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spQueryToHtmlTable] 
(
  @query nvarchar(MAX), --A query to turn into HTML format. It should not include an ORDER BY clause.
  @orderBy nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --An optional ORDER BY clause. It should contain the words 'ORDER BY'.
  @html nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT --The HTML output of the procedure.
)
AS
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @orderBy IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @orderBy = ''  
  END

  SET @orderBy = REPLACE(@orderBy, '''', '''''');

  DECLARE @realQuery nvarchar(MAX) = '
    DECLARE @headerRow nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX);    

    SELECT * INTO #dynSql FROM (' + @query + ') sub;

    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '', '''''''', '', '''') + ''['' + name + ''] AS ''''td''''''
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @cols = ''SET @html = CAST(( SELECT '' + @cols + '' FROM #dynSql ' + @orderBy + ' FOR XML PATH(''''tr''''), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS nvarchar(max))''    

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cols, N''@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT'', @html=@html OUTPUT

    SELECT @headerRow = COALESCE(@headerRow + '''', '''') + ''<th>'' + name + ''</th>'' 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @headerRow = ''<tr>'' + @headerRow + ''</tr>'';

    SET @html = ''<table border="1">'' + @headerRow + @html + ''</table>'';    
    ';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @realQuery, N'@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @html=@html OUTPUT
END
GO
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);
EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,  @query = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.People', @orderBy = N'ORDER BY FirstName';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Foo',
    @recipients = 'bar@baz.com;',
    @subject = 'HTML email',
    @body = @html,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
```

Related: Here is similar code to turn any arbitrary query into a [CSV string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530891/1195036).

Comment: This is something I have looked for and had been planning to write. This is a more flexible version of what you normally see. I edited to fix the line for the RealQuery is really one line which if someone copies and pastes will not work as is. Good code, Very Good code.

Comment: This doesn't generate cells for `NULL` values. To fix this, change `ELEMENTS)` to `ELEMENTS XSINIL)`. The null cells will then have the attribute `xsi:nil="true"`, which could possibly be replaced with special styling. Great procedure!

Comment: Excellent! Additionally, if you want to run a stored procedure, you can insert your stored procedure results into a temporary table and select from that instead

Comment: Realize its a bit old, but just wanted to drop a note that this is an *awesome* answer. Best solution I've seen anywhere to this problem. Major kudos to @mgsam

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid, but I don't understand how to implement this answer even after reading the instructions. They don't make any sense to me. Is this Ruby? Do I just bind the @query to the query string and run the file? It'd be nice to have some idiot-friendly instructions.

Comment: For a very mighty approach using `XQuery FLWOR` you might chech [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204)

Comment: @JohnCurry, this is just standard (T)SQL.  Notice the "sql" tag.

Comment: Is there a way to use this without setting up the mail server (Such as just printing out the HTML to a file or the screen somehow)?

Comment: Using this with SP_WHOISACTIVE  generates black sql_texts, I just can't understand why.

Comment: if I have used temporary table in the @ query (Select * INTO #temptbl), then it's returning error i.e. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'

Comment: Can you convert to synapse version?

Comment: I love this, but good lord all those '''s are giving me a headache to try to figure out.
I've used it but am struggling to adapt to my use-case where some of the columns include html elements, and the '<'s are being changed to '&lt;'s etc...

I can change it afterwards, but I'd like to add a table-valued parameter to the SP that allows you to pass styling options...

Answer (score 13):

This might give you some idea --

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp 
( 
  [Rank]  [int],
  [Player Name]  [varchar](128),
  [Ranking Points] [int],
  [Country]  [varchar](128)
)


INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 1,'Rafael Nadal',12390,'Spain'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Roger Federer',7965,'Switzerland'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Novak Djokovic',7880,'Serbia'


DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT [Rank] AS 'td','',[Player Name] AS 'td','',
       [Ranking Points] AS 'td','', Country AS 'td'
FROM  #Temp ORDER BY Rank 
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))


SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Tennis Rankings Info</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Rank </th> <th> Player Name </th> <th> Ranking Points </th> <th> Country </th></tr>'    


SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL ALERTING', -- replace with your SQL Database Mail Profile 
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'bruhaspathy@hotmail.com', -- replace with your email address
@subject = 'E-mail in Tabular Format' ;


DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: Interesting approach, though I don't understand why you have the extra blank string after each field; can you please explain the functionality/need of that piece? Another piece which I need hence was unable to use your solution, was to add a class to certain rows (i.e every other row to have another CSS class).

Comment: @Eli I would guess that MS SQL XML combines like named fields as one.  An empty space or null value that has no name will not serialize, separating `td` values in to their own columns rather than a concatenation.

Comment: To add zebra stripes to Mahesh's code, you can add the "@class" instruction:

SET @xml = CAST(( SELECT CASE WHEN [Rank] % 2 = 0 THEN 'even' ELSE 'odd' END "@class", [Rank] AS 'td','',[Player Name] AS 'td','',
       [Ranking Points] AS 'td','', Country AS 'td'
FROM  #Temp ORDER BY Rank 
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

Answer (score 1):

Here my common used script below. I use this for running scripts on two tables/views with SQL job and send results as two HTML tables via mail. Ofcourse you should create mail profile before run this.

```
DECLARE @mailfrom varchar(max)
DECLARE @subject varchar(100)
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX), @tableHTML1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @tableHTML2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @mailbody NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Table1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @Table2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @jobName varchar(100)
SELECT @jobName = name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID))

-- If the result set is not empty then fill the Table1 HTML table
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table1]) > 0
BEGIN
SET @Table1 = N''
SELECT @Table1 = @Table1 + '<tr style="font-size:13px;background-color:#FFFFFF">' + 
    '<td>' + ColumnText + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + CAST(ColumnNumber as nvarchar(30)) + '</td>' + '</tr>'  
FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table1]
ORDER BY ColumnText,ColumnNumber

SET @tableHTML1 = 
N'<table border="1" align="Left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;" >' +
N'<tr style ="font-size:13px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF"> 
<th align=left>ColumnTextHeader1</th>
<th align=left>ColumnNumberHeader2</th> </tr>' + @Table1 + '</table>'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @tableHTML1 = N''
SET @Table1 = N''
END


-- If the result set is not empty then fill the Table2 HTML table
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table2]) > 0
BEGIN
SET @Table2 = N''
SELECT @Table2 = @Table2 + '<tr style="font-size:13px;background-color:#FFFFFF">' + 
    '<td>' + ColumnText + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + CAST(ColumnNumber as nvarchar(30)) + '</td>' + '</tr>'  
FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table2]
ORDER BY ColumnText,ColumnNumber

SET @tableHTML2 = 
N'<table border="1" align="Left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="color:black;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;" >' +
N'<tr style ="font-size:13px;font-weight: normal;background: #FFFFFF"> 
<th align=left>ColumnTextHeader1</th>
<th align=left>ColumnNumberHeader2</th> </tr>' + @Table2 + '</table>'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @tableHTML2 = N''
SET @Table2 = N''
END

SET @tableHTML = @tableHTML1 + @tableHTML2

-- If result sets from Table1 and Table2 are empty, then don't sent mail.
IF (SELECT @tableHTML) <> ''
BEGIN
SET @mailbody = N' Write mail text here<br><br>' + @tableHTML
SELECT @mailfrom = 'SQL Server <' + cast(SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNETBIOS') as varchar(50)) + '@domain.com>'
SELECT @subject = N'Mail Subject [Job: ' + @jobName + ']'
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name= 'mailprofilename',
    @recipients= '<mailaddress@domain.com>',
    @from_address = @mailfrom,
    @reply_to = '<mailaddress@domain.com>',
    @subject = @subject,
    @body = @mailbody,
    @body_format = 'HTML'
--   ,@importance = 'HIGH'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

[JustinStolle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367310/84424)'s answer in a different way.  A few notes:

- The `print` statement may truncate the string to 4000 characters, but my test string for example was 9520 characters in length.
- The `[tr/th]` indicates hierarchy, e.g., `<tr><th>...</th></tr>`.
- The `[@name]` adds fields as XML attributes.
- MS SQL XML concatenates fields of the same name, so `null` in between fields prevents that.

---

```
declare @body nvarchar(max)

select @body = cast((
    select N'2' [@cellpadding], N'2' [@cellspacing], N'1' [@border],
           N'Database Table' [tr/th], null [tr/td],
           N'Entity Count' [tr/th], null [tr/td],
           N'Total Rows' [tr/th], null,
           (select  object_name( object_id ) [td], null,
                    count( distinct name ) [td], null,
                    count( * )  [td], null
             from sys.columns
             group by object_name( object_id )
             for xml path('tr'), type)
        for xml path('table'), type
        ) as nvarchar(max))

print @body  -- only shows up to 4000 characters depending
```

Answer (score 0):

based on JustinStolle code (thank you), I wanted a solution that could be generic without having to specify the column names.

This sample is using the data of a temp table but of course it can be adjusted as required.

Here is what I got:

```
DECLARE @htmlTH VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @htmlTD VARCHAR(MAX)

--get header, columns name
SELECT @htmlTH = @htmlTH + '<TH>' +  name + '</TH>' FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#results')

--convert table to XML PATH, ELEMENTS XSINIL is used to include NULL values
SET @htmlTD = (SELECT * FROM #results FOR XML PATH('TR'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)

--convert the way ELEMENTS XSINIL display NULL to display word NULL
SET @htmlTD = REPLACE(@htmlTD, ' xsi:nil="true"/>', '>NULL</TD>')
SET @htmlTD = REPLACE(@htmlTD, '<TR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">', '<TR>')

--FOR XML PATH will set tags for each column name, <columnName1>abc</columnName1><columnName2>def</columnName2>
--this will replace all the column names with TD (html table data tag)
SELECT @htmlTD = REPLACE(REPLACE(@htmlTD, '<' + name + '>', '<TD>'), '</' + name + '>', '</TD>')
FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#results')


SELECT '<TABLE cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">'
     + '<TR>' + @htmlTH + '</TR>'
     + @htmlTD
     + '</TABLE>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose someone found his way here and does not understand the usage of the marked answer SQL, please read mine... it is edited and works. Table:staff, columns:staffname,staffphone and staffDOB

```
declare @body varchar(max)

--    Create the body
set @body = cast( (
select td = dbtable + '</td><td>' + cast( phone as varchar(30) ) + '</td><td>' + cast( age as varchar(30) )
from (
      select dbtable  = StaffName ,
               phone = staffphone,
               age          = datepart(day,staffdob)
      from staff
      group by staffname,StaffPhone,StaffDOB  
      ) as d
for xml path( 'tr' ), type ) as varchar(max) )
set @body = '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">'
              + '<tr><th>Database Table</th><th>Entity Count</th><th>Total Rows</th></tr>'
              + replace( replace( @body, '&lt;', '<' ), '&gt;', '>' )
              + '<table>'
print @body
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried printing Multiple Tables using Mahesh Example above. Posting for convenience of others

```
USE MyDataBase

DECLARE @RECORDS_THAT_NEED_TO_SEND_EMAIL TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                                                POS_ID INT, 
                                                POS_NUM VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
                                                DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
                                                DISTRICT VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                                                COST_LOC VARCHAR(100) NULL,
                                                EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NULL)

INSERT INTO @RECORDS_THAT_NEED_TO_SEND_EMAIL(POS_ID,POS_NUM,DISTRICT,COST_LOC,DEPARTMENT,EMPLOYEE_NAME) 
SELECT uvwpos.POS_ID,uvwpos.POS_NUM,uvwpos.DISTRICT, uvwpos.COST_LOC,uvwpos.DEPARTMENT,uvemp.LAST_NAME + ' ' + uvemp.FIRST_NAME 
FROM uvwPOSITIONS uvwpos LEFT JOIN uvwEMPLOYEES uvemp 
on uvemp.POS_ID=uvwpos.POS_ID 
WHERE uvwpos.ACTIVE=1 AND uvwpos.POS_NUM LIKE 'sde%'AND (
(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(uvwpos.DEPARTMENT,LEN(uvwpos.DEPARTMENT)-1))) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(uvwpos.COST_LOC))) 
OR (uvwpos.DISTRICT IS NULL) 
OR (uvwpos.COST_LOC IS NULL)   )

DECLARE @RESULT_DISTRICT_ISEMPTY varchar(4000)
DECLARE @RESULT_COST_LOC_ISEMPTY varchar(4000)
DECLARE @RESULT_COST_LOC__AND_DISTRICT_NOT_MATCHING  varchar(4000)
DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @HTMLHEADER VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @HTMLFOOTER VARCHAR(100)
SET @HTMLHEADER='<html><body>'
SET @HTMLFOOTER ='</body></html>'
SET @RESULT_DISTRICT_ISEMPTY  = '';
SET @BODY =@HTMLHEADER+ '<H3>PositionNumber where District is Empty.</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> POS_ID </th> <th> POS_NUM </th> <th> DEPARTMENT </th> <th> DISTRICT </th> <th> COST_LOC </th></tr>'   

SET @RESULT_DISTRICT_ISEMPTY = CAST(( SELECT [POS_ID] AS 'td','',RTRIM([POS_NUM]) AS 'td','',
     ISNULL(LEFT(DEPARTMENT,LEN(DEPARTMENT)-1),'          ') AS 'td','', ISNULL([DISTRICT],'        ')  AS 'td','',ISNULL([COST_LOC],'           ') AS 'td'
FROM  @RECORDS_THAT_NEED_TO_SEND_EMAIL 
WHERE DISTRICT IS NULL
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SET @BODY = @BODY + @RESULT_DISTRICT_ISEMPTY +'</table>'


DECLARE @RESULT_COST_LOC_ISEMPTY_HEADER VARCHAR(400)
SET @RESULT_COST_LOC_ISEMPTY_HEADER  ='<H3>PositionNumber where COST_LOC is Empty.</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> POS_ID </th> <th> POS_NUM </th> <th> DEPARTMENT </th> <th> DISTRICT </th> <th> COST_LOC </th></tr>'   

SET @RESULT_COST_LOC_ISEMPTY = CAST(( SELECT [POS_ID] AS 'td','',RTRIM([POS_NUM]) AS 'td','',
     ISNULL(LEFT(DEPARTMENT,LEN(DEPARTMENT)-1),'          ') AS 'td','', ISNULL([DISTRICT],'        ')  AS 'td','',ISNULL([COST_LOC],'           ') AS 'td'
FROM  @RECORDS_THAT_NEED_TO_SEND_EMAIL 
WHERE COST_LOC IS NULL
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SET @BODY = @BODY + @RESULT_COST_LOC_ISEMPTY_HEADER+ @RESULT_COST_LOC_ISEMPTY +'</table>'

DECLARE @RESULT_COST_LOC__AND_DISTRICT_NOT_MATCHING_HEADER VARCHAR(400)
SET @RESULT_COST_LOC__AND_DISTRICT_NOT_MATCHING_HEADER='<H3>PositionNumber where Department and Cost Center are Not Macthing.</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> POS_ID </th> <th> POS_NUM </th> <th> DEPARTMENT </th> <th> DISTRICT </th> <th> COST_LOC </th></tr>'   
SET @RESULT_COST_LOC__AND_DISTRICT_NOT_MATCHING = CAST(( SELECT [POS_ID] AS 'td','',RTRIM([POS_NUM]) AS 'td','',
     ISNULL(LEFT(DEPARTMENT,LEN(DEPARTMENT)-1),'          ') AS 'td','', ISNULL([DISTRICT],'        ')  AS 'td','',ISNULL([COST_LOC],'           ') AS 'td'
FROM  @RECORDS_THAT_NEED_TO_SEND_EMAIL 
WHERE 
(RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(DEPARTMENT,LEN(DEPARTMENT)-1))) <> RTRIM(LTRIM(COST_LOC)))
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SET @BODY = @BODY + @RESULT_COST_LOC__AND_DISTRICT_NOT_MATCHING_HEADER+ @RESULT_COST_LOC__AND_DISTRICT_NOT_MATCHING  +'</table>'


SET @BODY = @BODY + @HTMLFOOTER

USE DDDADMINISTRATION_DB
--SEND EMAIL
exec DDDADMINISTRATION_DB.dbo.uspSMTP_NOTIFY_HTML
                              @EmailSubject = 'District,Department & CostCenter Discrepancies', 
                              @EmailMessage = @BODY, 
                              @ToEmailAddress  = 'Slohani@azdes.gov', 
                              @FromEmailAddress  = 'Slohani@azdes.gov' 


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'MY POROFILE', -- replace with your SQL Database Mail Profile 
@body = @BODY,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'Recepients@internalmail.com', -- replace with your email address
@subject = 'District,Department & CostCenter Discrepancies' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers use variables and SET operations. Here's a way to do it within a select statement. Just drop this in as a column in your existing select.

```
    (SELECT 
        '<table style=''font-family:"Verdana"; font-size: 10pt''>'
                    + '<tr bgcolor="#9DBED4"><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>'
                    + replace( replace( body, '&lt;', '<' ), '&gt;', '>' )
                    + '</table>'
    FROM
    (
        select cast( (
            select td = cast(col1 as varchar(5)) + '</td><td align="right">' + col2 + '</td><td>' + col3 + '</td><td align="right">' + cast(col4 as varchar(5)) + '</td><td align="right">' + cast(col5 as varchar(5)) + '</td>'
            from (
                    select col1  = col1,
                            col2 = col2,
                            col3 = col3,
                            col4 = col4,
                            col5 = col5
                    from m_LineLevel as onml
                    where onml.pkey = oni.pkey
                    ) as d
            for xml path( 'tr' ), type ) as varchar(max) ) as body
    ) as bodycte) as LineTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code, I have prepared for generating the HTML file for documentation which includes Table Name and Purpose in each table and Table Metadata information. It might be helpful!

```
use Your_Database_Name;
print '<!DOCTYPE html>'
PRINT '<html><body>'
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT T.name AS TableName 
      FROM sys.objects AS T
     WHERE T.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
     ORDER BY T.name
OPEN tableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @tableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    print '<table>'
    print '<tr><td><b>Table Name: <b></td><td>'+@tableName+'</td></tr>'
    print '<tr><td><b>Prupose: <b></td><td>????YOu can Fill later????</td></tr>'
    print '</table>'

    print '<table>'
    print '<tr><th>ColumnName</th><th>DataType</th><th>Size</th><th>PrecScale</th><th>Nullable</th><th>Default</th><th>Identity</th><th>Remarks</th></tr>'
    SELECT  concat('<tr><td>',
            LEFT(C.name, 30) /*AS ColumnName*/,'</td><td>',
           LEFT(ISC.DATA_TYPE, 10) /*AS DataType*/,'</td><td>',
           C.max_length /*AS Size*/,'</td><td>',
           CAST(P.precision AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(P.scale AS VARCHAR(4)) /*AS PrecScale*/,'</td><td>',
           CASE WHEN C.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'Null' ELSE 'No Null' END /*AS [Nullable]*/,'</td><td>',
           LEFT(ISNULL(ISC.COLUMN_DEFAULT, ' '), 5)  /*AS [Default]*/,'</td><td>',
           CASE WHEN C.is_identity = 1 THEN 'Identity' ELSE '' END /*AS [Identity]*/,'</td><td></td></tr>')
    FROM   sys.objects AS T
           JOIN sys.columns AS C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
           JOIN sys.types AS P ON C.system_type_id = P.system_type_id and c.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
           JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS ISC ON T.name = ISC.TABLE_NAME AND C.name = ISC.COLUMN_NAME
    WHERE  T.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
      AND  T.name = @tableName
    ORDER BY T.name, ISC.ORDINAL_POSITION
    print '</table>'
    print '</br>'
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @tableName

END

CLOSE tableCursor
DEALLOCATE tableCursor
SET NOCOUNT OFF
PRINT '</body></html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation: any query result to html table.

I'm creating some helper procedures to achieve this. These helper procedures are flexible, and may be reused in various contexts.

- `fnValidateDynamicSql` - to validate passed dynamic statement
- `spAlterTblByRs` - to save any SQL statement result to `#table`. Allows to completely remove dynamic SQL from the code
- `spQueryResultAsHtmlTable` - creates html table from any passed SQL  statement

Enjoy :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnValidateDynamicSql]
    (@Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),     /* dynamic sql statement */
     @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)   /* parameters, if dynamic SQL is parametrized. Pass NULL if there are no params */
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    /*  Check or @Sql statement is valid
     *  Returns NULL if valid, exception message otherwise   
     */
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(1000);

    IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL
               FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](@Sql, @Params, 0)
               WHERE [error_message] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [error_number] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [error_severity] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [error_state] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [error_type] IS NOT NULL
                 AND [error_type_desc] IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = [error_message]
        FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](@Sql, @Params, 0)
        WHERE [column_ordinal] = 0;
    END;
    
    IF NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Sql)), '') IS NULL 
       SET @Result = '@Sql is NULL';

    RETURN @Result;
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAlterTblByRs]
    @ErrCode  INT OUT,
    @ErrMsg   VARCHAR(4000) OUT,    
    @Sql      NVARCHAR(MAX),         /* Query stmt  */
    @Params   NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,  /* Query parameters (like in sp_executesql) */
    @Tbl      NVARCHAR(256),         /* Table name */
    @DummyCol NVARCHAR(256),         /* Dummy column name (will be removed) */
    @PopulateTable BIT = NULL        /* If 1, then populate altered table by @Sql query data */ 
AS
    /* Alters table by recordset to be used. Populates data, if required. */    
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ARITHABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @ERR_CODE_OK        INT =   0
            ,   @ERR_CODE_FAILURE   INT =   50000;

        SET @ErrCode = @ERR_CODE_OK;

        
        IF NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Tbl)), '') IS NULL THROW @ERR_CODE_FAILURE, '@Tbl is empty', 1;
        IF NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@DummyCol)), '') IS NULL THROW @ERR_CODE_FAILURE, '@DummyCol is empty', 1;


        IF [dbo].[fnValidateDynamicSql](@Sql, @Params) IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrMsg = 'Invalid @Sql received: ' + [dbo].[fnValidateDynamicSql](@Sql, @Params);
            ;THROW @ERR_CODE_FAILURE, @ErrMsg, 1;
        END;


        DECLARE @AlterStmt      NVARCHAR(MAX) = SPACE(0);
        DECLARE @RemColStmt     NVARCHAR(MAX) = SPACE(0);   
             
        --  prepare existing table alter Stmt by previuos rs structure
        SET @AlterStmt = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tbl + ' ADD ' + CHAR(13);

        ;WITH [rsStructure] AS (
            SELECT
                    [name]
                ,   [system_type_name]
                ,   [is_nullable]            
            FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](
                            @Sql
                        ,   @Params
                        ,   0
            )       
        )
        SELECT 
             @AlterStmt += QUOTENAME([name]) + SPACE(1) + [system_type_name] + IIF([is_nullable] = 0, ' NOT NULL' , SPACE(0)) + ',' + CHAR(13)
        FROM [rsStructure];

        SET @AlterStmt = LEFT(@AlterStmt, LEN(@AlterStmt) - 2);

        --  finally update table structure
        EXEC [sys].[sp_executesql] @AlterStmt; 
        

        --  remove dummy column
        SET @RemColStmt = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tbl + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @DummyCol;
        EXEC [sys].[sp_executesql] @RemColStmt; 

        --  populate table with @Sql statement data
        IF @PopulateTable = 1
        BEGIN
            EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @tbl + ' ' + @sql);
        END;
        
        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    
        /* Use some error formatting sp instead */
        SELECT  @ErrCode    =   ERROR_NUMBER()
            ,   @ErrMsg     =   ERROR_MESSAGE();

    END CATCH

    RETURN @ErrCode;

END


GO

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spQueryResultAsHtmlTable]
    @ErrCode    INT             OUT
,   @ErrMsg     NVARCHAR(4000)  OUT
,   @Sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @Params     NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @HtmlTable  NVARCHAR(MAX)   OUT
AS
/*  Makes Html table by result, returned by provided @Query 
 */
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ARITHABORT ON;
        
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @ERR_CODE_OK        INT =   0
            ,   @ERR_CODE_FAILED    INT =   50000;          

        SET @ErrCode = @ERR_CODE_OK;

        DECLARE @HtmlAsHml  XML
            ,   @ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)   =   SPACE(0);       

        IF NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Sql)), SPACE(0)) IS NULL THROW @ERR_CODE_FAILED, 'Empty @Query received', 1;
                    
                
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#QueryResult') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [#QueryResult];
        CREATE TABLE [#QueryResult] ([dummy_col] BIT);

        EXEC [dbo].[spAlterTblByRs]
            @ErrCode        =   @ErrCode        OUT
        ,   @ErrMsg         =   @ErrMsg         OUT
        ,   @Sql            =   @Sql            
        ,   @Params         =   @Params         
        ,   @Tbl            =   '#QueryResult'  
        ,   @DummyCol       =   'dummy_col'     
        ,   @PopulateTable  =   1;

        IF @ErrCode <> 0 THROW @ErrCode, @ErrMsg, 1;
                    
            
        SELECT @ColumnList += IIF([column_ordinal] = 1, SPACE(0), ',') + '[td] = [' + [name] + ']'
        FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](
            @Sql    /*  @tsql                       */
        ,   @Params /*  @params                     */
        ,   0       /*  @browse_information_mode    */      
        )       
        ORDER BY [column_ordinal] ASC;


        DECLARE @h  XML
        ,       @d  XML;    

        /* Prepare headers */
        ;WITH [headers] AS (
            SELECT [h] = CONVERT(XML, (SELECT 
                [th] = [name] 
            FROM [sys].[dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](
                @Sql    /*  @tsql                       */
            ,   @Params /*  @params                     */
            ,   0       /*  @browse_information_mode    */      
            )   
            ORDER BY [column_ordinal] ASC
            FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('tr')))
        )
        SELECT @h = [h] FROM [headers];
            
        
        /* Prepare rows */
        SET @sql = N'
        ;WITH [data] AS (
            SELECT [d] = (SELECT    
                ' + @ColumnList + '
            FROM [#QueryResult] 
            FOR XML RAW (''tr''), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE)
        )       
        SELECT @d = [d] FROM [data]';

        SET @params = N'@d xml output';

        EXECUTE [sp_executesql] 
            @stmt   =   @sql
        ,   @params =   @params     
        ,   @d      =   @d      OUTPUT;
        

        /* Make table html */
        SET  @HtmlAsHml = CONVERT(XML, (SELECT [*] = @h, [*] = @d FOR XML PATH('table')));

        SET @HtmlAsHml.modify('insert attribute cellpadding {"2"} into (table)[1]')
        SET @HtmlAsHml.modify('insert attribute cellspacing {"2"} into (table)[1]')
        SET @HtmlAsHml.modify('insert attribute border {"1"} into (table)[1]')
    
        
        /* Prepare value to be returned */
        SET @HtmlTable = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @HtmlAsHml);
        
               
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH             

        /* Use some error formatting sp instead */
        SELECT  @ErrCode    =   ERROR_NUMBER()
            ,   @ErrMsg     =   ERROR_MESSAGE();

    END CATCH;
    
    RETURN @ErrCode;
    
END;
GO

/* Usage */

DECLARE
    @ErrCode    INT             
,   @ErrMsg     NVARCHAR(4000)  
,   @Sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)   =   'select top (10) * from sys.tables'
,   @HtmlTable  NVARCHAR(MAX);

EXEC [dbo].[spQueryResultAsHtmlTable]
    @ErrCode    =   @ErrCode    OUT
,   @ErrMsg     =   @ErrMsg     OUT
,   @Sql        =   @Sql        
,   @Params     =   NULL        
,   @HtmlTable  =   @HtmlTable  OUT; /* YOur desired html table here */

IF @ErrCode <> 0 THROW @ErrCode, @ErrMsg, 1;
```