# xquery return xml elements in for loop?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have the following xquery for Sql server 2008 tables.

```
declare @tableName sysname = 'tableName'
declare @colNames xml = (select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = @tableName for xml path(''), elements)
select @colNames.query('<html><body>
<table>
<tr>
{
    for $c in /COLUMN_NAME
    return data($c)[1]
}
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
')
```

However, it returns the following xml.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>col1col2col3col4col5</tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the expected result is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to change `return data($c)[1]` to `concat("<th>", data($c)[1], "</th>")`. However, the `<` and `>` were escaped to `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create HTML Table with SQL FOR XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml)

Comment: Hi, if this is still interesting for your, especially due to the comment below (*Is it possible to append the data of the table to xml under the column header too?*), I'd like to point you to an [answer to a related question I just answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for $c in /COLUMN_NAME
return element th { data($c)[1] }
```

or

```
for $c in /COLUMN_NAME
return <th>{ data($c)[1] }</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could do it directly in your query.

```
select
  (
  select COLUMN_NAME as '*'
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
  where TABLE_NAME = @tableName
  for xml path('th'), root('tr'), type
  ) as "table"
for xml path('body'), root('html')
```

or

```
select
  (
  select COLUMN_NAME as th
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
  where TABLE_NAME = @tableName
  for xml path(''), type
  ) as "html/body/table/tr"
for xml path('')
```

Comment: Great solution too. Is it possible to append the data of the table to xml under the column header too? I think I will need to create a new question for it.

Comment: @NickW Don't have the time right now for this but I did something similar before. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7087899/569436