# Create HTML Table with SQL FOR XML for Auto Database Report email

Tags: html, sql-server

I would like to create an SQL Script for database auto email for database report of Data in different tables. Currently, I am unable to create table form for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create html logic by your own. Means style format and other properties of html tag as given below links.

This are the links please check it out.

[Create HTML Table with SQL FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17730.sql-server-result-set-in-an-html-email.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2010/06/15/Building-HTML-Emails-With-SQL-Server-and-XML/