# SQL to html using XML?

Tags: html, sql, xml

ok here is what im trying to do I have an sql query within a ssis package that I need to transform into html for storing into an sql table field varbinary(max)

here is the source table (simplified):

<kbd>Customer ID</kbd>
    <kbd>Question</kbd>       
    <kbd>Answer</kbd>
    
   <kbd>1</kbd>                  
    <kbd>how are you?</kbd>
    <kbd>ok</kbd>         
    <kbd>1</kbd>                  
    <kbd>like beans?</kbd>    
    <kbd>mm yes</kbd>
    
    <kbd>2</kbd>                  
    <kbd>how are you?</kbd>
    <kbd>fine</kbd>        
    <kbd>2</kbd>                  
    <kbd>like beans?</kbd>    
    <kbd>yuk</kbd>

The output ideally needs to be:

<kbd>CustomerID</kbd>
    <kbd>html</kbd>         
    
    <kbd>1</kbd>                 
    <kbd>see below</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>                 
    <kbd>see below</kbd>

where the html is the table of the questions / answers converted to varbinary(max) grouped by customerID. Thinking of using for xml or something like that but super stuck on this. Help much appreciated.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Question</th>
<th>Answer</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>How are you?</td>
<td>ok</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>like beans?</td>
<td>mm yes</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you are actually asking for

Comment: simplified: I want to group the source table by customerID and store the Question and Answer as a html table string.

Comment: i think you might be missing a tag. html and xml cant process sql results

Comment: sql has an xml for.. something similar to this but with a group by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. neither html nor xml can execute SQL statements. what web platform are you using.

Comment: I dont want to execute html or xml from sql I want to format the query results into HTML to store in varbinary(max)

Comment: How are you obtaining the data from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
DECLARE @questions TABLE(QuestID INT IDENTITY, CustomerID INT, Question VARCHAR(100),Answer VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @questions(CustomerID,Question,Answer) VALUES
 (1,'How are you?','ok')
,(1,'Like beans?','mm yes')
,(2,'How are you?','fine')
,(2,'Like beans?','yuk');

SELECT CustomerID
      ,(
            SELECT       
                   (
                        SELECT 'Question' AS [th],''
                              ,'Answer' AS [th],''
                        FOR XML PATH('tr'),TYPE
                   )
                  ,(    
                        SELECT  Question AS [td],''
                                ,Answer AS [td],'' 
                        FROM @questions AS q 
                        WHERE q.CustomerID=Cust.CustomerID
                        FOR XML PATH('tr'),TYPE
                    )
            FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('table'),TYPE
        )
FROM @questions AS Cust
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: @GregWhite You might look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml) There I just posted a new solution which will create a `XHTML` table from any `SELECT` generically. Might be interesting...

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit tedious, but this can be achieved by using XML functions, that most DBMS's support. For example, here is the documentation for PostgreSQL:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-xml.html

Your sql would look something like this:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("table",
          (XMLELEMENT("tr",
             XMLCONCAT(
                XMLELEMENT("th",'Question'),
                XMLELEMENT("th",'Answer'))
              ...etc.
           ))
FROM mytable
GROUP BY customerID;
```

Use subqueries to get the questions and answers per customer.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml path with `,type` you can define which values should go to a th and which to a td:

```
declare @cust table(custid int, que nvarchar(50), ans nvarchar(50))

insert into @cust values (1, 'how are you?', 'ok')
, (1, 'like beans?', 'yes')
, (2, 'how are you?', 'good')
, (2, 'like beans?', 'no')

 select c.custid, 
(select 
    (select th
            from (select 'Question' th
                    union all
                  select 'Answer') d 
          for xml path(''),type) tr --first row for the headers
          , (select 
                (select que for xml path('td'),type) --question column
                , (select ans for xml path('td'),type) --answer column
                from (select custid, que, ans
                        FROM @cust i
                        where i.custid = c.custid
                    ) data 
           for xml path ('tr'),type) --each question answer in a row
           for xml path('table'), type) --for the whole table 
 from @cust c
 group by c.custid
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a35a3/1/0)

Comment: Your result will include a "que" and a "ans" tag before each inner element. You can avoid this by adding `select que as [*]` (similar with "ans") - And secondly this can be done much easier. Look at my answer...