# How to convert xml as a table or html table in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, xml, parameters, html-table, procedure

xml is a type in sqlserver, now I want to pass a table variable to procedure, but you must define the table as type (use "create type").
So I think I can use xml as a variable to pass into the procedure as parameters.

```
declare @tv  table
(
  id int, 
  username varchar(50),
  department varchar(50) 
  
)
insert into @tv values(1,'tom','finance'),(2,'mark','business');

declare @xml xml;
set @xml  =(select * from @tv for xml  path('row') ,type )
select @xml  ;
```

I want to use table like @tv as parameter, pass it to procedure,
and get the result like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>tom</td><td>finance</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>mark</td><td>business</td></tr>
</table>
```

I know it can be done by this:

`select id as td ,username as td , department as td from @tv for  xml raw('tr'),elements`

but I want it dynamic, because I don't know the column name when it pass as parameters.

### UPDATE (taken from OP's comment)

further more ,I want get the table column name in the result html ,like

```
<table> <tr> <td>id</td> <td>username</td> <td>department</td> </tr> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>tom</td> <td>finance</td> </tr> <tr> <td>2</td> <td>mark</td> <td>business</td> </tr> </table>
```

,so when I pass a table variable(or xml ) to function ,it return like this

Comment: If I pass xml variable to procedure parameters , how can it be query like table . or insert into  table variable ,so I can query such as ( select * from  @xml  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find a much enhanced version of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204).

*old answer*:

> because I don't know the column name when it pass as parameters

This makes it impossible, to call something like `SELECT * FROM`... You might think about dynamic SQL, but there is a great alternative: [FLWOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx)

```
declare @tv  table
(
  id int, 
  username varchar(50),
  department varchar(50) 

)
insert into @tv values(1,'tom','finance'),(2,'mark','business');

SELECT
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @tv 
    FOR XML PATH('tr'),TYPE
).query('for $tr in /tr
         return <tr>
           {
             for $td in $tr/*
             return <td>{$td/text()}</td>
           }
                </tr>')
FOR XML PATH('table')
```

The `.query()` will run through your XML and re-create it as demanded.

The result:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>tom</td>
    <td>finance</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>mark</td>
    <td>business</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

##UPDATE
##This is a solution with a `FUNCTION` on `XML`-base using [FLWOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx)

It will transform any `SELECT` into a XHTML table: The call is as easy as this:

```
SELECT dbo.CreateHTMLTable((SELECT TOP 5 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL));
```

That's the code

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateHTMLTable(@SelectForXmlRawElementsXsinil XML)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN

RETURN
(
    SELECT  
    @SelectForXmlRawElementsXsinil.query('let $first:=/row[1]
                return 
                <tr> 
                {
                for $th in $first/*
                return <td>{local-name($th)}</td>
                }
                </tr>') AS thead
    ,@SelectForXmlRawElementsXsinil.query('for $tr in /row
                 return 
                 <tr>
                 {
                 for $td in $tr/*
                 return <td>{string($td)}</td>
                 }
                 </tr>') AS tbody
    FOR XML PATH('table'),TYPE
);
END
GO
```

--a mock-up-table with data

```
declare @tv  table
(
  id int, 
  username varchar(50),
  department varchar(50) 
)
--NULL value in row=2!!!
insert into @tv values(1,'tom','finance'),(2,NULL,'business');
```

--That's the way you use it

```
SELECT dbo.CreateHTMLTable((SELECT * FROM @tv FOR XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL));
```

--Clean-Up

```
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CreateHTMLTable;
```

returns **be aware of the NULL value in last row!**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>username</td>
      <td>department</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>tom</td>
      <td>finance</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td />
      <td>business</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

##UPDATE Possible Enhancements

- You can control the layout easily via `CSS`
- You might pass in class names for `table`, `thead`, `tbody`... for better CSS-control
- One could pass in a *one-row-footer* with aggregated values as second parameter and append it as `<tfoot>`

Comment: Thanks ,further more ,I want get the table column name in the result html ,like `<table>
 <tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>username</td>
  <td>department</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>tom</td>
    <td>finance</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>mark</td>
    <td>business</td>
  </tr>
</table>`    ,so when  I pass a table variable(or xml )  to function ,it return like this .

Comment: @openkava, see my update. Please upvote and accept, if this solves your issue, thx!

Comment: @openkava, one more update, I'm not so familiar with `html` and improved the table's structure...