# SQL pad column content with tabs instead of spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, padding

I am dynamically creating a column via a SELECT statement. The content of this column is a string which is then used as content for an e-mail.

The text looks like this:

```
text 1 | text 2 | text 3 | ...
text 123 | text 223 | text 323 | ...
```

as you see, the two lines are not aligned. The expected output should be like this:

```
text 1   | text 2   | text 3   | ...
text 123 | text 223 | text 323 | ...
```

The obvious solution is to pad each field in order for each field to have the same size. for this i used the following code:

```
LEFT(field1 + REPLICATE(' ', 20), 20)
```

My issue is, that in Outlook the text is still not shown properly aligned even though, if I copy the text into Notepad, it is properly aligned. The reason is, that Outlook uses Arial for displaying text-mails and in Arial blank-spaces do not have the same size as the other characters. Hence the padding does not yield the expected result.

My question now is: Is there some other way to use this *padding approach* in order to get same size displayed fields in Outlook Mails? Probably by padding with tabs? But I think my approach above then does not work anymore...

Comment: Dude SQL is not meant for this. Simply copy paste the result to excel and add border then copy that to outlook

Comment: Prepare HTML content for your email.

Comment: 100% agree with @Prdp but you may want to look at `sp_send_dbmail` which you can send results as plain-text, html, or as an attachment... including excel.

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204) I found a fully generic approach to transfer (almost) any `SELECT` into a html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the TAB, it dawned on me that you were talking about trailing tabs

```
Declare @Table table (SomeField varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values
('Some Text'),
('Some Longer Text with more')

Select String = SomeField+replicate(char(9),(30-Len(SomeField))/4)+'|'
From @Table
```

Returns

```
Some Text                   |
Some Longer Text with more  |
```

Comment: hm almost there, but not quite. see this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/un6FnMN.png  for the first string (first line, it has 21 characters) 5 tabs are created. for the second string (20 characters) four tabs are created. the math is correct, but it yields one tab too much for the first string. note, that I changed in your code `30` to `40`

Comment: okay, for some reason, strings of size 4,8,12,16, and so on had one additional tab which shouldnt have been there. I now check for these cases and remove one of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want (or can't) create the HTML as @techspider and @Shnugo mentioned, you could simply cast your string as a char(20)

```
cast(field1 as char(20))
```

For Example

```
Select '| '+cast('text1' as char(20))+' | '+cast('text1' as char(20))+'|'
```

Returns

```
| text1                | text1               |
```

Comment: do you know a solution where I can pad with `tabs`? the issue is that I need a different amount of tabs, because the fields can be of different size.

Comment: @beta Not clear what you are looking for.  A visual would help.  Replicate(char(9),5)  (5 tabs)  or Replicate('\t',5) (encoded)

Comment: because strings are of different size, replicating always 5 tabs does not help. for some shorter strings, i maybe need 6 tabs. for longer strings, i need only 3 tabs in order to get same size fields. you know what i mean?

Comment: @beta the 5 was just an example.  This can be an expression.  Tabs generate a consistent lengths depending on target (some 4, others 10), in other words, 3 tabs + a 4 character string will not be the same length as 3 tabs plus a 5 character string.   cast as char or padding is the only way to enforce lengths.

Comment: I think the point is character width... If OP could enforce a *fixed-width* font simple padding would be perfect. With modern fonts you must rely on presentation logic of the client. Tabs might be supported - or not... HTML table might be supported - or not...

Comment: @Shnugo As you mentioned, HTML Formatted email would be the way to go.  That would eliminate all but one concern  (client doesn't accept HTML email, which I suspect would be very rare).

Comment: @Shnugo Just dawned on me that OP was talking about trailing blanks .. added another answer

Comment: yes, i was talking about trailing blanks. and @Shnugo is correct: Outlook-Client doesnt use fixed-width font for displaying raw-text-mails. hence, padding with blanks does not work. of course, HTML would be the way to go, but our code does currently not support it and we would need a quick solution. but of course, we already requested to get HTML mails.. but still would like to get it to work without HTML. I can try your other solution on monday.