# In Store Procedure when i get data from table and set to xml format. I want to set background color in <td> tag

Tags: sql-server, xml

Set background color based on td when i parse date row in xml format

```
declare @xml1 xml    
SET @xml1 = CAST((select Region AS 'td','',
      [MTD Total] AS 'td','',
      [MTD] AS 'td','',
      [MTD Percentage] AS 'td','',
      [FTD Total] AS 'td','',
      [FTD] AS 'td','',
      [FTD Percentage] AS 'td',''
FROM #temp
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
select  @xml1
```

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204). You'll find a function to create a HTML table out of any select statement with support for style tags, CSS, links...

Comment: @shnugo u know how to set color by row wise. Column wise color set working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

You should either

- use [this function to create a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204)
- insert a `class` attribute and use CSS
- use CSS for the `<td>` class, if you can set this globally

If you really want to continue with the above you might try something like this:

```
declare @xml1 xml =
(   
select
      'blue' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      Region AS 'td','',
      'red' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      [MTD Total] AS 'td','',
      'white' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      [MTD] AS 'td','',
      'green' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      [MTD Percentage] AS 'td','',
      'yellow' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      [FTD Total] AS 'td','',
      'black' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      [FTD] AS 'td','',
      'blue' AS [td/@bgcolor], 
      [FTD Percentage] AS 'td',''
FROM #temp
FOR XML PATH('tr'),TYPE
);

select  @xml1
```

The same way you might introduce a general `style` attribute...