# Concatenating html comma seperated using for xml < &lt

Tags: html, sql-server, xml, t-sql, concatenation

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will convert the results of a SQL query into a HTML string which will display them in a HTML table.

The problem I have is I am using `FOR XML` to get a comma-separated list of td values and then trying to concatenate it, however when I do that, it loses the `<` and `>` characters and replaces them with the XML `&lt` and `&gt` - I need it to show me it as `<>`.

here is the part of the query that does this:

```
    declare C cursor for
    select (convert(nvarchar(max),(SELECT "th/@width"='50', th = name
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns isc
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##tempcolumns') 
            for xml PATH(N''), TYPE)))
    open C
    declare @L varchar(max)
    fetch next from C into @L
    close C
    deallocate C

    DECLARE @html nvarchar(max), @table nvarchar(max), @test nvarchar(max), @html2 nvarchar(max) 
    SET @html =  
    N'<html> <head><title>TestHTML</title></head>' + CHAR(10) + 
    N'<body style="font-family: Arial;">' + 
    N'<h1>Companies2</h1></font>' + 
    '<table style="float: left; width:100%;">' + 
    N'<tr>' + 
            @L +
    N'</tr>' + CHAR(10); 

    SELECT @table = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),(SELECT (
    SELECT  '<td>' + STUFF( ( SELECT td = ', '  + '[' + isc.name + ']' 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns isc
    WHERE isc.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##tempcolumns') FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,5,'')) FROM ##temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE))


    SET @html = @html + @table + CHAR(10) +  
                N'</table></body></html>' 

    SELECT @table
```

However, this is what it returns:

```
&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Open]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Partially Ordered]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Lost]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Not Pursued]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Expired (Past 90 days)]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;, [Pending]&lt;/td&gt;
```

How do I get it to show for example `<td> [Reasons_Code] </td>` and not `&lt;td&gt; [Reasons_Code]&lt;/td&gt`

Comment: You should not build XML via string concatenation! Using a `CURSOR` is something one should avoid too. Your code shows *procedural thinking* while one should think *set based*. As you are trying to build up an `HTML` table obviously, you might read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7086393/5089204. Read the younger answers (especially mine :-) ) to find much better approaches for this...

Comment: This is exactly what I am after, thank you so much!

Comment: Well, than it's appropriate to close this as duplicate... Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

By stacking `for xml` statements, you are telling SQL Server that you want to hold *values* that contain reserved XML characters in an XML string, for example:

```
<ActualTag>Your values that contain a < and > special character</ActualTag>
```

This is obviously impossible.  Just because you are using tricks to remove the tags that would otherwise be present, you are still dealing with XML *values*.

Either change your approach to your string building or just `select` the `value` held in your final XML variable:

```
declare @x xml = '<ActualTag>Your values that contain a &lt; and &gt; special character</ActualTag>';
select @x.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

Output:

```
Your values that contain a < and > special character
```

Comment: To be honest: XML should not be created on string level at all... In this case - at least I think so - the closest hint might be `SELECT CAST(@SomeStringThatLooksLikeXML AS XML)`, MIght be the OP is looking for `, TYPE` in connection with your suggested `.value()` - hint. But the whole approach is wrong...

Comment: @Shnugo  Oh certainly, agree on all points.