# Send Email from SQL Server database with multiple tables in email body

Tags: sql-server, xml, email, html-table, xhtml

I am challenged by the following task.

Here is my question in detail: I need to send email from SQL Server with HTML table format that the email body will have several tables.

1. Query will be from database like

   ```
   SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
   FROM Table 
   WHERE DateField >= Somedate
   ```
2. `Field3` will be the factor to separate the tables, hence, the result will be grouped by `Field3` values and put on separate tables
3. The email content will be more or less like the following (screenshot is attached)

   ```
   Section: Field3 Value1      
   Field   Field2  Field3
      1    AA      Value1
      2    BB      Value1
      3    CC      Value1

   Section: Field3 Value2      
   Field   Field2  Field3
      1    OO      Value2
      2    XX      Value2
      3    VV      Value2

   Section: Field3 Value3      
   Field   Field2  Field3
      1    qwqw    Value3
      2    GGGG    Value3
      3    COCO    Value3
   ```

I have tried cursor, however, it will only return only one of the tables (based on the first FETCH value). Any help is appreciated

[sample result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soJr4.png)

Comment: Why not use [Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-deploy-and-manage-mobile-and-paginated-reports)?

Comment: don't use cursors... use temp tables and apply the html table tags if don't want to use SSRS

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204) I provide a function, that will create a fully blown HTML table out of any select.

Comment: Re: maSTAShuFu   - can you give me some example on the use of temp table and return n number of result tables with HTML tags? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the function [I provide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204) you can do this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Field1 INT, Field2 VARCHAR(10), Field3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'AA','Value1')
,(2,'BB','Value1')
,(3,'CC','Value1')
,(1,'OO','Value2')
,(2,'XX','Value2')
,(3,'VV','Value2')
,(1,'qwqw','Value3')
,(2,'GGGG','Value3')
,(3,'COCO','Value3');
```

--The query will build this as one big `XHTML`

```
SELECT (SELECT N'Section: Field3="Value1"' AS p FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
,dbo.CreateHTMLTable
        (
        (SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE Field3='Value1' FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)
        ,NULL,NULL,NULL
        )
,(SELECT N'Section: Field3="Value2"' AS p FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
,dbo.CreateHTMLTable
        (
        (SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE Field3='Value2' FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)
        ,NULL,NULL,NULL
        )
,(SELECT N'Section: Field3="Value3"' AS p FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
,dbo.CreateHTMLTable
        (
        (SELECT * FROM @tbl WHERE Field3='Value3' FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)
        ,NULL,NULL,NULL
        )  
FOR XML PATH('body'),ROOT('html');
```

This is the result (click *run code snippet* to see the result formatted)

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Section: Field3="Value1"</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Field1</th>
          <th>Field2</th>
          <th>Field3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>AA</td>
          <td>Value1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>BB</td>
          <td>Value1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>CC</td>
          <td>Value1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Section: Field3="Value2"</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Field1</th>
          <th>Field2</th>
          <th>Field3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>OO</td>
          <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>XX</td>
          <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>VV</td>
          <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Section: Field3="Value3"</p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Field1</th>
          <th>Field2</th>
          <th>Field3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>qwqw</td>
          <td>Value3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>GGGG</td>
          <td>Value3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>COCO</td>
          <td>Value3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Embedd a `<style>` node to add CSS formatting

Find further possibilities and background at the link provided above...

Comment: I have used this in the past and it works great. Top marks to Shnugo