# Multiple IF EXISTS statement

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that sends daily report for 2 operational machines. I also show on report `misfire count` per machine but if 1 machine has `0` misfires and the other has more than `0` the Misfire report section will be skipped and not reported.

First I want to check and see if any `items` exist for specific day and if not send report saying "No results found" or whatever, if they do exist then check to see if any `misfires` exist on both machines. I want to attach only the stats from the machine that has more than `0` and skip misfire report altogether if they both have `0`. I will show what a report looks like that shows Daily Stats that has `misfires` on both machines.

[image]

If say `TILT_1` reports `0` misfires and say `TILT_2` reports `20` misfires on DAILY SORTER STATS portion then both TILT_1 and TILT_2 MISFIRE REPORT are not attached to report at all. In this instance I would only want to attach TILT_2 MISFIRE REPORT. I hope I am explaining correctly.

Here is the book of a script. Thanks for your help.

```
DECLARE 
    @Now       DATETIME    ,
    @Monday    DATETIME    ,
    @Friday    DATETIME    ,
    @StartTime VARCHAR(16) ,
    @EndTime   VARCHAR(16) ,
    @Message   VARCHAR (50),
    @FileName  VARCHAR (50),
    @Final     VARCHAR (50)
SET @StartTime = '12:01:00AM'
SET @EndTime   = '11:59:59PM'
SET @Now       = GETDATE()
SET @Monday    = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now), -0)
SET @Friday    = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now), -0)
SET @Message   = 'No results found for' 
SET @FileName = CONVERT(varchar(30), GETDATE(), 107) + ' Sorter Stats 17P' 
SET @Final     = CAST(@message as varchar(70)) + ' ' + CAST(DATENAME (WEEKDAY, @Now)AS VARCHAR (30)) + ',' + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @Now, 107)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
IF EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM  [dbo].[StatData]
          WHERE CreationTime BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                                 AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime 
                                 AND SorterID IN ('TILT_1', 'TILT_2') 
          HAVING FLOOR(SUM(Throws)/2) = 0 
         ) 
BEGIN
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'My_profile',
@recipients = 'whatever@yep.com' ,
@subject = @FileName,
@importance = 'High',
@body = @Final,
@query_result_separator = '                          ';
RETURN
END
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ELSE
IF EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM [dbo].[MisfireLog]
           WHERE RecordedPeriod BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND WorkstationID IN ('T01', 'T02')
           HAVING  COUNT (MisfireOrder) = 0
           )      
BEGIN 
--------------------START SORTER STATS.NO MISFIRE INFO-----------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body varchar(max)
declare @TableHead varchar(max)
declare @TableTail varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id as int
declare @statusMsg as varchar(max)
declare @Error as varchar(max) 
declare @Note as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id = null
set @statusMsg = null
set @Error = null
set @Note = null
Set @TableTail = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead = 
'<html><head>' +
'<H1 style="color: #000000">Daily Sorter Stats</H1>' +
'<style>' +
'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
'</style>' +
'</head>' +
'<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
'<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
'<td align=center><b>Sorter</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Items</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Misfire</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body= (Select 
[TD] = t1.Sorter, 
[TD] = t1.Items,
[TD] = t2.Misfire
FROM
(
SELECT Items = floor(sum(Throws)/2)
       ,Sorter = 'TILT_1' 
FROM   [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                    AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime 
                    AND SorterID = 'TILT_1'
)t1
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT Misfire = isnull(FLOOR(sum(misfire)),0)
       ,'TILT_1' AS Sorter
FROM   [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE  HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND SorterID = 'TILT_1'
)t2
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT DisabledTrays = isnull(COUNT(SorterID),0)
       ,'TILT_1' AS Sorter
FROM   [dbo].[DisabledCarriers]
WHERE  SorterID  = 'TILT_1'
)t3
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body = Replace(@Body, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body = @TableHead + @Body + @TableTail
-- return output--
Select @Body
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body1 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead1 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail1 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id1 as int
declare @statusMsg1 as varchar(max)
declare @Error1 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note1 as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id1 = null
set @statusMsg1 = null
set @Error1 = null
set @Note1 = null
Set @TableTail1 = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead1 = 
'<html><head>' +
'<style>' +
'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
'</style>' +
'</head>' +
'<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
'<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
'<td align=center><b>Sorter</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Items</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Misfire</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body1= (Select 
[TD] = t1.Sorter, 
[TD] = t1.Items,
[TD] = t2.Misfire
FROM
(
SELECT Items = isnull(floor(sum(Throws)/2),0)
       ,'TILT_2' AS Sorter
FROM   [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE  HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND SorterID = 'TILT_2'
)t1
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT Misfire = isnull(FLOOR(sum(misfire)),0)
       , 'TILT_2' AS Sorter
FROM  [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                    AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                    AND SorterID = 'TILT_2'
)t2
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body1 = Replace(@Body1, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body1 = Replace(@Body1, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body1 = Replace(@Body1, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body1 = Replace(@Body1, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body1 = @TableHead1 + @Body1 + @TableTail1
-- return output--
Select @Body1
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
--Email
DECLARE  @BodyAll  varchar(max)
SET @BodyAll = @Body + @Body1 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
 @profile_name ='My_profile',
 @recipients = 'whatever@yep.com',
 @subject = @FileName,
 @body = @BodyAll,
 @body_format = 'HTML'
RETURN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------ALL STATS.WITH MISFIRES----
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body2 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead2 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail2 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id2 as int
declare @statusMsg2 as varchar(max)
declare @Error2 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note2 as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id2 = null
set @statusMsg2 = null
set @Error2 = null
set @Note2 = null
Set @TableTail2 = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead2 = 
'<html><head>' +
'<H1 style="color: #000000">Daily Sorter Stats</H1>' +
'<style>' +
'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
'</style>' +
'</head>' +
'<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
'<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
'<td align=center><b>Sorter</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Items</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Misfire</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body2= (Select 
[TD] = t1.Sorter, 
[TD] = t1.Items,
[TD] = t2.Misfire       
FROM
(
SELECT Items = floor(sum(Throws)/2)
       ,Sorter = 'TILT_1' 
FROM   [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                    AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime 
                    AND SorterID = 'TILT_1'
)t1
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT Misfire = isnull(FLOOR(sum(misfire)),0)
       ,'TILT_1' AS Sorter
FROM   [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE  HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND SorterID = 'TILT_1'
)t2
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body2 = Replace(@Body2, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body2 = Replace(@Body2, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body2 = Replace(@Body2, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body2 = Replace(@Body2, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')

Set @Body2 = @TableHead2 + @Body2 + @TableTail2
-- return output--
Select @Body2
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body3 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead3 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail3 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id3 as int
declare @statusMsg3 as varchar(max)
declare @Error3 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note3 as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id3 = null
set @statusMsg3 = null
set @Error3= null
set @Note3 = null
Set @TableTail3 = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead3 = 
'<html><head>' +
'<style>' +
'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
'</style>' +
'</head>' +
'<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
'<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
'<td align=center><b>Sorter</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Items</b></td>' +
'<td align=center><b>Misfire</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body3= (Select 
[TD] = t1.Sorter, 
[TD] = t1.Items,
[TD] = t2.Misfire
FROM
(
SELECT Items = isnull(floor(sum(Throws)/2),0)
       ,'TILT_2' AS Sorter
FROM   [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE  HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND SorterID = 'TILT_2'
)t1
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT Misfire = isnull(FLOOR(sum(misfire)),0)
       , 'TILT_2' AS Sorter
FROM  [dbo].[StatData]
WHERE HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                    AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                    AND SorterID = 'TILT_2'
)t2
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body3 = Replace(@Body3, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body3 = Replace(@Body3, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body3 = Replace(@Body3, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body3 = Replace(@Body3, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body3 = @TableHead3 + @Body3 + @TableTail3
-- return output--
Select @Body3
-------------------------------------INSERT MISFIRE STATS HERE---
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body4 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead4 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail4 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id4 as int
declare @statusMsg4 as varchar(max)
declare @Error4 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note4 as varchar(max)

Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id4 = null
set @statusMsg4 = null
set @Error4 = null
set @Note4 = null
Set @TableTail4 = '</table></body></html>';

--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead4 = '<html><head>' +
 '<H1 style="color: #000000">Tilt 1 Misfire Report</H1>' +
 '<style>' +
 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
 '</style>' +
 '</head>' +
 '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
 '<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
 '<td align=center><b>Misfire Count</b></td>' +
 '<td align=center><b>Chute ID</b></td></tr>';

--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body4= (Select 
[TD] = isnull(COUNT (MisfireOrder),0),
[TD] = ChuteID
            from  [dbo].[MisfireLog]
            where RecordedPeriod BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND WorkstationID   = 'T01'
            group by ChuteID
            order by COUNT (MisfireOrder) desc
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body4 = Replace(@Body4, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body4 = Replace(@Body4, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body4 = Replace(@Body4, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body4 = Replace(@Body4, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body4 = @TableHead4 + @Body4 + @TableTail4
-- return output--
Select @Body4
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body5 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead5 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail5 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id5 as int
declare @statusMsg5 as varchar(max)
declare @Error5 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note5 as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id5 = null
set @statusMsg5 = null
set @Error5 = null
set @Note5 = null
Set @TableTail5 = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead5 = '<html><head>' +
 --'<H1 style="color: #000000">Tilt 2 Misfire Report</H1>' +
 '<style>' +
 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
 '</style>' +
 '</head>' +
 '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
 '<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
 '<td align=center><b>Misfire Count</b></td>' +
 '<td align=center><b>Carrier ID</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body5= (Select 
[TD] = isnull(COUNT (MisfireOrder),0),
[TD] = CarrierID
            from [dbo].[MisfireLog]
            where RecordedPeriod BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND WorkstationID   = 'T01'
            group by CarrierID
            order by COUNT (MisfireOrder) desc
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body5 = Replace(@Body5, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body5 = Replace(@Body5, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body5 = Replace(@Body5, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body5 = Replace(@Body5, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body5 = @TableHead5 + @Body5 + @TableTail5
-- return output--
Select @Body5
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body6 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead6 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail6 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id6 as int
declare @statusMsg6 as varchar(max)
declare @Error6 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note6 as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id6 = null
set @statusMsg6 = null
set @Error6 = null
set @Note6 = null
Set @TableTail6 = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead6= '<html><head>' +
 '<H1 style="color: #000000">Tilt 2 Misfire Report</H1>' +
 '<style>' +
 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
 '</style>' +
 '</head>' +
 '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
 '<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
 '<td align=center><b>Misfire Count</b></td>' +
 '<td align=center><b>Chute ID</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body6= (Select 
[TD] = isnull(COUNT (MisfireOrder),0),
[TD] = ChuteID
            from [dbo].[MisfireLog]
            where RecordedPeriod BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND WorkstationID   = 'T02'
            group by ChuteID
            order by COUNT (MisfireOrder) desc
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body6 = Replace(@Body6, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body6 = Replace(@Body6, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body6 = Replace(@Body6, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body6 = Replace(@Body6, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body6 = @TableHead6 + @Body6 + @TableTail6
-- return output--
Select @Body6
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Email Query--
DECLARE @Body7 varchar(max)
declare @TableHead7 varchar(max)
declare @TableTail7 varchar(max)
declare @mailitem_id7 as int
declare @statusMsg7 as varchar(max)
declare @Error7 as varchar(max) 
declare @Note7 as varchar(max)
Set NoCount On;
set @mailitem_id7 = null
set @statusMsg7 = null
set @Error7 = null
set @Note7 = null
Set @TableTail7 = '</table></body></html>';
--HTML layout--
Set @TableHead7 = '<html><head>' +
 --'<H1 style="color: #000000">Tilt 2 Misfire Report</H1>' +
 '<style>' +
 'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:9pt;color:Black;} ' +
 '</style>' +
 '</head>' +
 '<body><table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
 '<tr bgcolor=#F6AC5D>'+
 '<td align=center><b>Misfire Count</b></td>' +
 '<td align=center><b>Carrier ID</b></td></tr>';
--Select information for the Report-- 
Select @Body7= (Select 
[TD] = isnull(COUNT (MisfireOrder),0),
[TD] = CarrierID
            from [dbo].[MisfireLog]
            where RecordedPeriod BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                     AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                     AND WorkstationID   = 'T02'
            group by CarrierID
            order by COUNT (MisfireOrder) desc
For XML raw('tr'), Elements)
-- Replace the entity codes and row numbers
Set @Body7 = Replace(@Body7, '_x0020_', space(1))
Set @Body7 = Replace(@Body7, '_x003D_', '=')
Set @Body7 = Replace(@Body7, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#C6CFFF>')
Set @Body7 = Replace(@Body7, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')
Set @Body7 = @TableHead7 + @Body7 + @TableTail7
-- return output--
Select @Body7
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------
--Email
DECLARE  @BodyAll1  varchar(max)
SET @BodyAll1 = @Body2 + @Body3 + @Body4 + @Body5 + @Body6 + @Body7 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
 @profile_name ='My_profile',
 @recipients = 'whatever@yep.com',
 @subject = @FileName,
 @body = @BodyAll1,
 @body_format = 'HTML'
 END;
```

Comment: This is a large chunk of code. Can you reduce it to the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I answered a [related question here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48675214/5089204). This uses a function taking any `SELECT`, which will return a fully blown `XHTML` table. You can first insert your queries to temp tables, check your business logic and then use the provided approach to build your final `HTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `@Body4 + @Body5` are TILT1, and `@Body6 + @Body7` are TILT2

You eventually combine these with:

```
DECLARE  @BodyAll1  varchar(max)
SET @BodyAll1 = @Body2 + @Body3 + @Body4 + @Body5 + @Body6 + @Body7
```

It also looks like this is what gets the misfire count:

```
SELECT Misfire = isnull(FLOOR(sum(misfire)),0)
     , 'TILT_1' AS Sorter --or `TILT_2`
FROM  [PASTEUR].[WSS].[dbo].[StatData]
WHERE HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                AND SorterID = 'TILT_1' --or `TILT_2`
```

If that all is true, you should be able to simply wrap each TILT section in an `IF() BEGIN.. END`:

```
IF (SELECT ISNULL(FLOOR,SUM(MISFIRE)),0)
    FROM [PASTEUR].[WSS].[dbo].[StatData]
    WHERE HourBlock BETWEEN @Monday + ' ' + @StartTime
                        AND @Friday + ' ' + @EndTime
                        AND SorterID = 'TILT_1') > 0
BEGIN
    --All of @Body4 and @Body5 code
END
```

Then remove your current `IF EXISTS()`

You could also handle this when you set `@BodyAll1`, but this way you don't run all of that extra code to create the TILT tables unless you plan to use those tables.

Comment: Great I did a combo of both suggestions. Wrapped each TILT misfire section with appropriate `IF() BEGIN.. END` statements and then `SET @BodyAll1 = @Body2 + @Body3 + isnull(@Body4,' ') + isnull(@Body5,' ') + isnull(@Body6,' ') + isnull(@Body7,' ') ` like such. Thanks for help

Comment: Oh, and removed `IF EXISTS()` that looked from misfire count from top of SP