# How to edit my HTML codes for the output to highlight all cells of a row based on a condition?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `Stored Procedure` in `SQL Server 2012` which provides the `HTML` formatting of the output a `T-SQL` query. It works fine and is shown below:

```
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableHead VARCHAR(1000),
        @TableTail VARCHAR(1000)

SET @TableTail = '</table></body></html>' ;
SET @TableHead = '<html><head>' + '<style>'
    + 'td {border: solid black;border-width: 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font: 11px arial} '
    + '</style>' + '</head>' + '<body>' + 'This report is sent by the BI Server. Report generated on : '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 106) 
    + ' <br> <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' 
    + '<tr> <td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>StayYear</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>PropertyCode</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jan</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Feb</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Mar</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Apr</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>May</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jun</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jul</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Aug</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Sep</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Oct</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Nov</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Dec</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#0e914b><b>Total</b></td>';

SET @Body = ( SELECT td = StayYear, '',
                        td = PropertyCode, '',
                        td = Jan, '',
                        td = Feb, '',
                        td = Mar, '',
                        td = Apr, '',
                        td = May, '',
                        td = Jun, '',
                        td = Jul, '',
                        td = Aug, '',
                        td = Sep, '',
                        td = Oct, '',
                        td = Nov, '',
                        td = Dec, '',
                        td = Total, ''
              FROM  ITB 
              ORDER BY  [PropertyCode], [StayYear] DESC

                FOR   XML RAW('tr'),
                      ELEMENTS
            ) 


SET  @Body = @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail

SELECT  @Body

END
```

Here is an extract of the HTML output of the above query:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>td {border: solid black;border-width: 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font: 11px arial} 
</style>
</head>
<body>Report generated on : 22 Feb 2018 <br> 
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
<tr> 
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>StayYear</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>PropertyCode</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jan</b>
</td><td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Feb</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Mar</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Apr</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>May</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jun</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jul</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Aug</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Sep</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Oct</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Nov</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Dec</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#0e914b><b>Total</b></td>
<tr>
<td>2018</td>
<td>CDM</td>
<td>3261</td>
<td>2938</td>
<td>3054</td>
<td>2157</td>
<td>1948</td>
<td>889</td>
<td>1772</td>
<td>1620</td>
<td>872</td>
<td>1280</td>
<td>576</td>
<td>447</td>
<td>20814</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>2017</td>
<td>CDM</td>
<td>2989</td>
<td>2622</td>
<td>2484</td>
<td>1756</td>
<td>1326</td>
<td>552</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>321</td>
<td>465</td>
<td>225</td>
<td>12740</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>2018</td>
<td>EBA</td>
<td>1629</td>
<td>1494</td>
<td>1569</td>
<td>1085</td>
<td>1236</td>
<td>701</td>
<td>355</td>
<td>427</td>
<td>737</td>
<td>460</td>
<td>792</td>
<td>358</td>
<td>10843</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>2017</td>
<td>EBA</td>
<td>1778</td>
<td>1588</td>
<td>1580</td>
<td>1311</td>
<td>793</td>
<td>293</td>
<td>368</td>
<td>312</td>
<td>409</td>
<td>397</td>
<td>211</td>
<td>97</td>
<td>9137</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how the final `html` output (extract) looks:

[image]

I would like to modify my `HTML`codes in the `Stored Procedure` so that ALL rows relating to one same Property be highlighted in a same color.
That is, for Property 'CDM', all the rows will be highlighted in, say, Red and let's say Yellow for all Property called 'EBA'.

Can this be done in `HTML` or am I out of luck here?

Comment: You could add the propertycode as a class to all the rows, and then create css classes with background colors.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am not very conversant with HTML. Any links that could be helpful?

Comment: The idea is to add a style class to the table rows <tr class="'+PropertyCode+'">

then add a style class <style .CDM { background-color:"Blue" } .EBA { background-color:"Orange" } </style> 

Note that this is untested code html :D

Answer (score 0):

Add styles to the html based on the values like this: 
[Tryit editor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOPJ200H282P)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
td {border: solid black;border-width: 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font: 11px arial} 

.cdm td { 
    background-color: #0000FF;  color: white; } 

.eba td {
    background-color: #CC9999; color: white;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>Report generated on : 22 Feb 2018 <br> 
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
<tr> 
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>StayYear</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>PropertyCode</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jan</b>
</td><td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Feb</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Mar</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Apr</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>May</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jun</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jul</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Aug</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Sep</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Oct</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Nov</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Dec</b></td>
<td bgcolor=#0e914b><b>Total</b></td>
<tr class="cdm">
<td class="eba">2018</td>
<td>CDM</td>
<td>3261</td>
<td>2938</td>
<td>3054</td>
<td >2157</td>
<td>1948</td>
<td>889</td>
<td>1772</td>
<td>1620</td>
<td>872</td>
<td>1280</td>
<td>576</td>
<td>447</td>
<td>20814</td>
</tr><tr class="cdm">
<td>2017</td>
<td>CDM</td>
<td>2989</td>
<td>2622</td>
<td>2484</td>
<td>1756</td>
<td>1326</td>
<td>552</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>321</td>
<td>465</td>
<td>225</td>
<td>12740</td>
</tr><tr  class="eba">
<td>2018</td>
<td>EBA</td>
<td>1629</td>
<td>1494</td>
<td>1569</td>
<td>1085</td>
<td>1236</td>
<td>701</td>
<td>355</td>
<td>427</td>
<td>737</td>
<td>460</td>
<td>792</td>
<td>358</td>
<td>10843</td>
</tr><tr class="eba">
<td>2017</td>
<td>EBA</td>
<td>1778</td>
<td>1588</td>
<td>1580</td>
<td>1311</td>
<td>793</td>
<td>293</td>
<td>368</td>
<td>312</td>
<td>409</td>
<td>397</td>
<td>211</td>
<td>97</td>
<td>9137</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having trouble inserting the following codes in my SQL Query:

<tr class="cdm">

<td class="eba">2018</td>

</tr><tr class="cdm">

</tr><tr  class="eba">

</tr><tr class="eba">

Where do I insert them?

Comment: I am not used to XML in my queries, but i would guess you could try replacing the line

               FOR   XML RAW('tr'),

With 

               FOR   XML RAW('tr class='''+ISNULL([PropertyCode],'')+''''),

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the following error message in SQL:
Incorrect syntax near '+'

Comment: Maybe this can help you a bit more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml