# Convert SQL Server table into HTML using TSQL

Tags: sql-server

Below code works fine and convert table to HTML. It gives the results as HTML tables but it ignore HEADER (Column names), show only ROW values

I want to display Table-Column as first header in HTML table...

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_ConvertQuery2HTMLTable (
@SQLQuery NVARCHAR(3000))
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @columnslist NVARCHAR (1000) = ''
   DECLARE @restOfQuery NVARCHAR (2000) = ''
   DECLARE @DynTSQL NVARCHAR (3000)
   DECLARE @FROMPOS INT
   DECLARE @out table
        (
        out nvarchar(max)
        )


   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT @columnslist += 'ISNULL (' + NAME + ',' + '''' + ' ' + '''' + ')' + ','
   FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@SQLQuery, NULL, 0)

   SET @columnslist = left (@columnslist, Len (@columnslist) - 1)
   SET @FROMPOS = CHARINDEX ('FROM', @SQLQuery, 1)
   SET @restOfQuery = SUBSTRING(@SQLQuery, @FROMPOS, LEN(@SQLQuery) - @FROMPOS + 1)
   SET @columnslist = Replace (@columnslist, '),', ') as TD,')
   SET @columnslist += ' as TD'
   SET @DynTSQL = CONCAT (
         'SELECT (SELECT '
         , @columnslist
         ,' '
         , @restOfQuery
         ,' FOR XML RAW (''TR''), ELEMENTS, TYPE) AS ''TBODY'''
         ,' FOR XML PATH (''''), ROOT (''TABLE'')'
         )

   PRINT @DynTSQL

   EXEC (@DynTSQL)

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: I use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/6167855)  often for sending table results with dbmail, and you can even style it with CSS. If you want to see how I use it, you can check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/scsimon/sqlserver/blob/master/ufn_createHTMLtable)

Comment: @scsimon - can you add this as ANSWER. Great script, solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a script created by [Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo) which can [be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/6167855) with his comments, and methods to call it. I specifically use to build a HTML table when I need to send results with DBMAIL.

Here's how

```
/************************************************************************************************
Function to build a HTML table.

Created by Shnugo on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/6167855

Usage:

declare @body xml = 
    (select AdminTools.dbo.ufn_CreateHTMLTable (
    (select * from SomeTable for xml path ('row'),elements xsinil)
    ,null,null,null))

--CSS to make borders, which makes us change datatype
declare @body_html varchar(max)
set @body_html =  
    '<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
    .center
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    table,th
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table,tr
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table,td
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>' 
    + cast(@body as varchar(max))

Then @body_html for sp_send_dbmail

************************************************************************************************/

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_CreateHTMLTable]
(
    @SelectForXmlPathRowElementsXsinil XML
   ,@tblClass VARCHAR(100) --NULL to omit this class
   ,@thClass VARCHAR(100)  --same
   ,@tbClass VARCHAR(100)  --same
)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN

RETURN 
(
    SELECT @tblClass AS [@class]  
    ,@thClass AS [thead/@class]
    ,@SelectForXmlPathRowElementsXsinil.query(
              N'let $first:=/row[2]
                return 
                <tr> 
                {
                for $th in $first/*
                return <th>{if(not(empty($th/@caption))) then xs:string($th/@caption) else local-name($th)}</th>
                }
                </tr>') AS thead
    ,@tbClass AS [tbody/@class]
    ,@SelectForXmlPathRowElementsXsinil.query(
               N'for $tr in /row
                 return 
                 <tr>{$tr/@class}
                 {
                 for $td in $tr/*
                 return
                 if(empty($td/@link)) 
                 then <td>{$td/@class}{string($td)}</td>
                 else <td>{$td/@class}<a href="{$td/@link}">{string($td)}</a></td>
                 }
                 </tr>') AS tbody
    FOR XML PATH('table'),TYPE
) 
END

GO
```