# Add class to FOR XML PATH depending on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, case

I am building an html table to be injected into an email. I need this to be able to be ran directly out of sql. what I have so far is....

```
SELECT col1 AS 'td','',
    col2 AS 'td','',
    col3 AS 'td','',
    col4 AS 'td'
FROM TABLE
FOR XML PATH('tr'),ELEMENTS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

I Would like to add a class to the row so that i can control the font of the whole row depending upon the value of say col3.

I come from the programming world so i am not familiar with the sql equivalent of the following...
Pseudo Code Something like :

```
SELECT col1 AS 'td','',
    col2 AS 'td','',
    col3 AS 'td','',
    col4 AS 'td'
FROM TABLE
if col3 == 'fail' then FOR XML PATH('tr class=red'),ELEMENTS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
else if col3 == 'warn' then XML PATH('tr class=yellow'),ELEMENTS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
else FOR XML PATH('tr'),ELEMENTS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204). There you'll find a function, which will transfer any `SELECT` into an HTML-table with column headers, CSS-support down to cell-level and some nice goodies...

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery building the row's cells as the row's content and a `CASE` to assign different values to the row's `class` attribute.

```
SELECT CASE col4
          WHEN 'fail' THEN
            'red'
          WHEN 'warn' THEN
            'yellow'
          ELSE
            'green'
        END 'tr/@class',
        (SELECT col1 'td',
               '',
               col2 'td',
               '',
               col3 'td',
               '',
               col4 'td'
               FOR XML PATH(''),
                       TYPE) 'tr'
        FROM elbat
        FOR XML PATH('table');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=44abd8f3de07d147968d039e0226c6f3)