# How to convert sql query result to html tags with attributes

Tags: html, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Consider the below table in SQL-Server database:

```
Id    ProductName   Price    Size
-----------------------------------
1     T-Shirt       1000     M
2     Jeans         1800     L
```

How can I convert this table to below HTML string:

```
<div class='row' Id='1' size='M'>
    <div class='cell'>T-Shirt</div> 
    <div class='cell'>1000</div>
</div>
<div class='row' Id='2' size='L'>
    <div class='cell'>Jeans</div> 
    <div class='cell'>1800</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

First a *mockup-table* (Please do this yourself the next time):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,ProductName VARCHAR(100),Price DECIMAL(10,4),Size VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'T-Shirt',1000,'M')
,(2,'Jeans',1800,'L');
```

The query will use `FOR XML PATH`, which provides the highest control over the XML's naming

```
SELECT 'row' AS [@class]
      ,t.Id AS [@Id]
      ,t.Size AS [@size]
      ,'cell' AS [div/@class]
      ,t.ProductName AS [div]
      ,''
      ,'cell' AS [div/@class]
      ,t.Price AS [div]
FROM @tbl t
FOR XML PATH('div');
```

The result:

```
<div class="row" Id="1" size="M">
  <div class="cell">T-Shirt</div>
  <div class="cell">1000.0000</div>
</div>
<div class="row" Id="2" size="L">
  <div class="cell">Jeans</div>
  <div class="cell">1800.0000</div>
</div>
```

Hint1: We need the empty `,''` in the middle to start a new `<div>` element. Otherwise the engine would throw an error.

Hint2: The typical HTML-table [can be built with some XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487565/5089204)

Answer (score 0):

@Shnugo beat me to it. Alternatively you can simply do this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, ProductName VARCHAR(100), Price INT, SIZE CHAR(1));
INSERT @table VALUES (1,'T-Shirt',1000,'M'),(2,'Jeans',1800,'L');

SELECT 
'<div class="row" Id="'+LEFT(t.ID,30)+'" size="'+t.SIZE+'">
    <div class="cell">'+t.ProductName+'</div> 
    <div class="cell">'+LEFT(t.Price,30)+'</div>
</div>'
FROM @table AS t;
```

Which returns:

```
<div class="row" Id="1" size="M">
    <div class="cell">T-Shirt</div> 
    <div class="cell">1000</div>
</div>
<div class="row" Id="2" size="L">
    <div class="cell">Jeans</div> 
    <div class="cell">1800</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth to mention, that this will break with special characters... I'd avoid to create xml with string tools...

Comment: XQuery is my preference but you beat me to it. For something as simple as this it probably does not matter.

Comment: Don't you think, that a product's name can include a "&" or any other forbidden character?