# HTML - right align last 3 table columns using inline css

Tags: html, css, sql

I want to right-align the last 3 columns of this table which is being generated by SQL (the headers are redacted from the example code below). This is difficult since the data is generated by a FOR XML statement.

Because it will be sent by email, only inline styling should be used (I'm not sure why but it works).

I've tried `td:nth-last-child(-n+3)=text-align: right;` in various places but it's always ignored.

How do I right align the last 3 columns?

```
SET @xml = 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            [Cat] AS 'td','',
            [SubCat] AS 'td','',
            [Total1] AS 'td','', 
            [Total2] AS 'td', '', 
            [Total3] AS 'td', ''
        FROM  @SumTable ORDER BY Sort
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS 
    ) 
Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'<td>','<td style=
                                    "
                                        border: 1px solid lightgray; 
                                        padding: 4px;
                                    ">')

Select @xml
```

**Update**
Chris Porter's solution from this other question handles it perfectly. [Create HTML Table with SQL FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml)

When using FOR XML to generate the table, replace 'td' with temporary labels that can then be replaced. In the example below, I replace 'td' with 'tdt','tdr', and 'tdrb' and then replace them with the desired formatting.

```
SET @xml = --CAST(
    ( 
        SELECT 
            [Cat] AS 'tdt','',      --TDT=treat as Text
            [SubCat] AS 'tdt','',   --TDT=treat as Text
            [Total1] AS 'tdr','',   --TDR=Right align
            [Total2] AS 'tdr', '',  --TDR=Right align 
            [Total3] AS 'tdrb', ''  --TDRB=right align and bold
        FROM  @sumtable ORDER BY sort,[FT or PT],EnrollEndDtYm
        FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS 
    ) --AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

--The html table has been made but with placeholder element names. Let's replace them with what we want:
Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'<tdt>','<td style=
                                    "
                                        border: 1px solid lightgray; 
                                        padding: 4px;
                                    ">')
Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'<tdr>','<td style=
                                        "
                                            text-align: right;
                                            border: 1px solid lightgray; 
                                            padding: 4px;
                                        ">')
Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'<tdrb>','<td style=
                                        "
                                            text-align: right;
                                            font-weight: bold;
                                            border: 1px solid lightgray; 
                                            padding: 4px;
                                        ">')

Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'</tdt>','</td>')
Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'</tdr>','</td>')
Set @XML  = replace(@XML,'</tdrb>','</td>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `td:nth-last-child(-n+3)=text-align: right;`

You can try an inline CSS style to the `<td>` elements of those columns using the `nth-last-child()`

Also try changing

```
[Total1] AS 'td','',
[Total2] AS 'td', '',
[Total3] AS 'td', ''
```

For

```
[Total1] AS 'td','',
[Total2] AS 'td', '',
[Total3] AS 'td' style="text-align: right;", ''
```

This should add the inline style `text-align: right;` to the `<td>` element of the third column (Total3), which aligns the text to the right.

Sorry if I'm not providing the best example, it's kinda hard to test!

Comment: I know, right? Sorry it doesn't work. I also tried `[Total3] AS 'td style="text-align: right;", ''``` with the same result

Comment: you were on the right track. See above for the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use placeholder elements (instead of 'td') when creating the html table and then replacing them.

Please see the **Update** in the original post for more