# Increase size in HTML output in SQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert the SQL result to HTML format. But the result only gives first 66 rows out of 17266. Can you please let me know what I missed.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) 
set @query = N'<h1>BACKUP DATE</h1>'+  N'<style type=''text/css''>'+  N'table td,table th,table caption'+ N'table th{ background-color:3399FF;font-weight:bold; }'+  N'table caption { font-weight;bold;background-color:white; }'+  N'</style>'+  N'<table>'+  N'<caption>BDATE</caption>'+  N'<tr><th>DBNAME</th> <th>FDATE</th></tr>'+ cast(( SELECT td=NAME ,'',td=FDATE FROM TEMP  for xml path('tr'),type) as nvarchar(max)) +N'</table>'  select @query
```

Comment: what is the datatype of the output?

Comment: @SatheeshVariath Variath nvarchar

Comment: did you declare it as Nvarchar(max)?

Comment: @vijay,you should explain lil more on what you are trying to do.show some sample etc.anyway may be you should break your sql in several part and store each of them in varchar(max) then lastly combine them.

Comment: @SatheeshVariath I am using NVARCHAR(MAX) only. however the result displays only 8kb max.

Comment: @all This is my query

Comment: Just gotta love reading those queries in the comments.. :)

Comment: @NickyvV I tried to add the query along with my question But couldn't, got some message from stack overflow.. Don't know how u added :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar link, maybe you have not declared the output as nvarchar(max)?

[Convert a SQL query result table to an HTML table for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070053/convert-a-sql-query-result-table-to-an-html-table-for-email)