# How to save results of a SQL query to html file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-dictionary

I am running a SQL script I found [online](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1499/create-a-sql-server-data-dictionary-in-seconds-using-extended-properties/).  The script generates a data dictionary from extended properties data.  How can I save the results to an HTML file?

I prefer not changing the defaults, however I tried going into SQL server > Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > General > Changed "Default destination for results" to "Results to file" and set location to my documents folder.  I ran the SQL job this query is saved in and I do not see any new files in there.

I do not see a "save" in the original query either.

Original Query

```
Set nocount on

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(35)

DECLARE Tbls CURSOR 
FOR

Select distinct Table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
--put any exclusions here
--where table_name not like '%old' 
order by Table_name

OPEN Tbls

PRINT '<HTML><body>'

FETCH NEXT FROM Tbls
INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

PRINT '</br>'
PRINT '<table border="1">'
Print '<B>' + @TableName + '</B>'
PRINT '</br>'
--Get the Description of the table
--Characters 1-250
Select substring(cast(Value as varchar(1000)),1,250) FROM 
sys.extended_properties A
WHERE A.major_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
and name = 'MS_Description' and minor_id = 0

--Characters 251-500
Select substring(cast(Value as varchar(1000)),251, 250) FROM 
sys.extended_properties A
WHERE A.major_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
and name = 'MS_Description' and minor_id = 0

PRINT '<tr><b>'
--Set up the Column Headers for the Table
PRINT '<td><b>Column Name</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Description</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>InPrimaryKey</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>IsForeignKey</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>DataType</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Length</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Numeric Precision</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Numeric Scale</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Nullable</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Computed</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Identity</b></td>'
PRINT '<td><b>Default Value</b></td>'

--Get the Table Data
SELECT '</b></tr>',
'<tr>',
'<td>' + CAST(clmns.name AS VARCHAR(35)) + '</td>',
'<td>' + substring(ISNULL(CAST(exprop.value AS VARCHAR(255)),''),1,250),
substring(ISNULL(CAST(exprop.value AS VARCHAR(500)),''),251,250) + '</td>',
'<td>' + CAST(ISNULL(idxcol.index_column_id, 0)AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>',
'<td>' + CAST(ISNULL(
(SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkclmn
WHERE fkclmn.parent_column_id = clmns.column_id
AND fkclmn.parent_object_id = clmns.object_id
), 0) AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>',
'<td>' + CAST(udt.name AS CHAR(15)) + '</td>' ,
'<td>' + CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN typ.name IN (N'nchar', N'nvarchar') AND clmns.max_length <> -1
THEN clmns.max_length/2
ELSE clmns.max_length END AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>',
'<td>' + CAST(CAST(clmns.precision AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>',
'<td>' + CAST(CAST(clmns.scale AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>',
'<td>' + CAST(clmns.is_nullable AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>' ,
'<td>' + CAST(clmns.is_computed AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>' ,
'<td>' + CAST(clmns.is_identity AS VARCHAR(20)) + '</td>' ,
'<td>' + isnull(CAST(cnstr.definition AS VARCHAR(20)),'') + '</td>'
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns
ON clmns.object_id=tbl.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS idx
ON idx.object_id = clmns.object_id
AND 1 =idx.is_primary_key
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns AS idxcol
ON idxcol.index_id = idx.index_id
AND idxcol.column_id = clmns.column_id
AND idxcol.object_id = clmns.object_id
AND 0 = idxcol.is_included_column
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS udt
ON udt.user_type_id = clmns.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types AS typ
ON typ.user_type_id = clmns.system_type_id
AND typ.user_type_id = typ.system_type_id
LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints AS cnstr
ON cnstr.object_id=clmns.default_object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties exprop
ON exprop.major_id = clmns.object_id
AND exprop.minor_id = clmns.column_id
AND exprop.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE (tbl.name = @TableName and 
exprop.class = 1) --I don't wand to include comments on indexes
ORDER BY clmns.column_id ASC


PRINT '</tr></table>'

FETCH NEXT FROM Tbls
INTO @TableName
END


PRINT '</body></HTML>'

CLOSE Tbls
DEALLOCATE Tbls
```

Comment: This might help you [Convert a SQL query result table to an HTML table for email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070053/convert-a-sql-query-result-table-to-an-html-table-for-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your query and via the **messages** tab, if you right click you can `Save Result As`:

[image]

If you then change `Report files (*.rpt)` to `All Files (*.*)` you can type the name of a `.hmtl` file and save:

[image]

Comment: This is good because I can generate html files.  I want to automate this process.  I prefer to find a mechanism that allows automation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this script is being output via Print statements.

Check on the messages tab in SSMS.  You should be able to just copy and past from there into a HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.dbgizmo.net/ to generate the SQL properties. It also lets me save as HTML.  That's good enough for what I need to do.