# change value from query when running

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    'https://xxxxxx/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [AnnouncementID]) AS 'URL', 
    [Status] AS 'Code', 
    [Subject] AS 'Text', 
    (CASE 
        WHEN LEN([Subject]) > 500 
           THEN SUBSTRING([Subject], 0, 500) + '...' 
           ELSE [Subject] END) 
    AS 'ShortText'
FROM 
    [Announcement] 
WHERE 
    [Public] = 1 
    AND [Enable] = 1 
    AND GETDATE() BETWEEN [ActiveFrom] AND [ActiveTo] 
ORDER BY 
    [Status] ASC, [ActiveFrom] ASC
```

This query returns something like:

```
Url                 Code        Text    ShortText
-------------------------------------------------
https://xxxxxx/2    Enable      Text    Text
https://xxxxxx/1    Critical    Text    Text
```

I would like to Automatic change the text in `[Code]`.

- If Critical -> RED
- If Enabled -> YELLOW

How can I rewrite my query string above?

Comment: please post expected result and also tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: What i expect is that the out will change Enable -> YELLOW and Critical -> RED. so that the Query place the values

Comment: you might want to add more info on why enable should be changed to yellow and critical to red

Answer (score 1):

use a CASE:

```
CASE [Status]
    WHEN 'Enable' then 'YELLOW'
    WHEN 'Critical'  then 'RED'
END as 'Code'
```

or use a JOINED table with its values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly; you want to change the words Enable and Critical to YELLOW and RED respectively?

You can do this with a case statement, as you haven't tagged what DBMS you are using I can't really help with syntax but a rough idea would be;

```
SELECT 'https://xxxxxx/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [AnnouncementID]) AS 'URL', 
Case [Status]
  when 'Critical' then 'RED'
  when 'Enable' then 'YELLOW'
  end AS 'Code' , 
[Subject] AS 'Text', 
(CASE WHEN LEN([Subject]) > 500 THEN SUBSTRING([Subject], 0, 500) + '...' ELSE [Subject] END) AS 'ShortText' 

FROM [Announcement] 

WHERE [Public] = 1 
AND [Enable] = 1 
AND GETDATE() BETWEEN [ActiveFrom] AND [ActiveTo] 

ORDER BY [Status] ASC, [ActiveFrom] ASC
```

It's effectively saying if [Status] has the value 'Critical' display 'RED' or if has the value 'Enable' then display 'YELLOW'

Comment: Beaten by a minute!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070053/convert-a-sql-query-result-table-to-an-html-table-for-email). It references [this article](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/10/24/format-query-output-into-an-html-table-the-easy-way.aspx).
With some minor modifications, adding a few CASE statements based on the value of [Code] you could add a `<td style="color: red;">` or a `<td style="color: yellow;">`.

I hope that helps!