# Format query output into an html table

Tags: html, sql, sp-send-dbmail

I need the sql query result sent by e-mail to be in readable form. A change to html would allow to create results in the table. I need help implementing html in the code below.

```
USE msdb
go

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

IF EXISTS (select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny = 1)
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='PROFILE',
        @recipients='myadres@email.com',
        @query_result_header=0,
        @attach_query_result_as_file=0,
        @query="select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny=1 ORDER BY Kod",
        @body_format='text',
        @subject='warning';
END;

GO
```

The example contained in the 'MgSam' post [Convert a SQL query result table to an HTML table for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070053/convert-a-sql-query-result-table-to-an-html-table-for-email) actually solves the problem of convert to html and create table. However, I have no idea how to implement the 'if' condition.

According to the MgSam guidelines - the following code works - but if the query does not return data - the email is sent.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);

EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,  @query = "select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny = 1", @orderBy = N'ORDER BY Kod';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name='PROFILE',
    @recipients='my@email.com',
    @subject = 'WARNING',
    @body = @html,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a SQL query result table to an HTML table for email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070053/convert-a-sql-query-result-table-to-an-html-table-for-email)

Answer (score 0):

Well, IF statements in SQL Server are pretty straightforward, please take a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql

Based on your example:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);

EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,  @query = "select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny = 1", @orderBy = N'ORDER BY Kod';

IF DATALENGTH(@html) > 0 
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name='PROFILE',
    @recipients='my@email.com',
    @subject = 'WARNING',
    @body = @html,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
ELSE PRINT 'No results, don't email';
```

Comment: NB: you might need to adjust the ">0" limit if the conversion to table injects certain wrappers for an empty result set -- I haven't checked the underlying sproc.
E.g. if the @html results in "<html> </html>" with no data

Answer (score 0):

I used **IF EXISTS**. The code that works.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);

IF EXISTS (select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny = 1)

BEGIN

EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,  @query = "select Kod, Nazwa from DATABASE.dbo.Towar where Kod NOT LIKE '%?%' and AsId IN (205, 304, 289, 321, 306, 217, 261) and Aktywny = 1", @orderBy = N'ORDER BY Kod';

 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name='PROFILE',
    @recipients='my@email.com',
    @subject = 'WARNING',
    @body = @html,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query_no_truncate = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0;
    END;

GO
```