# Retrieving multiple rows in SQL Server in a sub query and concatenating them to a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with returning multiple values in a sub query and adding them to a string. Currently I am using:

```
Select master_key, (select parent_key 
                    from cmpower.dbo.dlnk 
                   where dlnk.parent_key = sbrv_table.masterkey) 
from cmpower.dbo.sbrv_table
```

The sub query returns multiple rows which I need to put into a comma delimited string.

I am not sure how to add the sub query results to a string to be returned with the main select query.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Did you see [this post][1]

It is the easiest I think.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455423/how-to-turn-one-column-of-a-table-into-a-csv-string-in-sql-server-without-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sbrv_table.master_key 
    , STUFF((select ', ' + parent_key [text()]
              from dbo.dlnk 
              where dlnk.parent_key = sbrv_table.masterkey
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
             .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS parent_key_List                      
FROM dbo.sbrv_table 
GROUP BY sbrv_table.master_key
```

Comment: spot on :), i have been trying to sort this all day with no luck. thankyou very much !!

Comment: would this work on a oracle database aswell? or will i have to doctor it?

Comment: Your question was tagged as Sql-server, it will definitely work with sql-server dont know about oracle sorry :)