# Combine 2 rows with same id into 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to combine below data according to the result shown as below in sql server.

Raw data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

i am not sure if i should use pivot. also, when i tried to concat it only able to combine the data from the same row.
It such a great help if you can help me with this. :)

Comment: have a read of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455423/how-to-turn-one-column-of-a-table-into-a-csv-string-in-sql-server-without-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer from [How to turn one column of a table into a csv string in SQL Server without using a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455423/how-to-turn-one-column-of-a-table-into-a-csv-string-in-sql-server-without-using) with string_agg should do the trick

```
SELECT
    salesid, 
    loyaltyid, 
    STRING_AGG(paymentitem, '+') AS paymentItem
FROM rawdata 
GROUP BY salesId, loyaltyId
ORDER BY salesId, loyaltyId;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL:

```
SELECT
    salesid, 
    loyaltyid, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(text, '+') AS paymentItem
FROM ABC 
GROUP BY salesId, loyaltyId
ORDER BY salesId, loyaltyId;
```